# How to create an event handler for multiple buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

In my C# project, I am creating a Hangman game that has a set of buttons which contains the alphabets from A to Z. All these buttons when clicked will execute the same method. 
I do not want to create an event handler for each of them one by one.
So how do I create a SINGLE event handler for all these buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subscribe same handler for all buttons and use `sender` to get button which raised event:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    // use Name or Tag of button
}
```

If your buttons named as alphabets `A`..`Z` then you can just use `button.Name` to get letter. If buttons have names like `buttonA`...`buttonZ` you can get substring from `button.Name` to get related letter (or `button.Name.Last()`). If buttons have names not related to alphabets, then you can use `Tag` property of button to set and get letter which is assigned to each button.

Comment: After I did what you told me, there was an error on my error list that said **'Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Form2' does not contain a definition for 'Sbtn_Click' and no extension method 'Sbtn_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Form2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @user2622438 looks like you had `Sbtn_Click` method, which was removed, but you still use it to subscribe to event. Go to source of error and remove subscription

Comment: Nevermind. The problem is solved. Thanks for your solution! :)

Comment: @user2622438 that means you deleted 26 methods definitions, but you still using them in your code. You should remove them manually. I believe you have button names `Abtn`..`Zbtn` then you can get letter with `button.Name.First()` or `button.Name.Substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have button1, button2, button3. You can point all the buttons click event to the same method on the design page:

or in the load event

```
button1.Click+=button_Click;
button2.Click+=button_Click;
button3.Click+=button_Click;

and you write the method

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button=sender as Button;
    // your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button) sender;
        //button name
    }
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycbsc785%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)