# I got a multiple buttons event handler here But I need to target only one button if it was clicked how do I do that?

Tags: c#

```
    private void btnCodeAkas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrTimerAkas.Start();
        tmrTimerTwoAkas.Start();
        
    }
```

But I need to target only one button if it was clicked how do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps look at the `sender`?

Comment: Compare `sender` against the buttons you have with an `if()` statement?

Comment: You've got into the event trap, put your code into a method and invoke it from only buttonClick events of buttons you want.

Comment: Is there more code?  If not, then why have multiple buttons fire that event?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, Why? Because lazyness :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an event handler for multiple buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570994/how-to-create-an-event-handler-for-multiple-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

well you can cast your sender to Control object so you can get the name of the button then you write your conditional logic.

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as Control;

        if (control.Name == "button1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Clicked {control.Name} button");
        }
        else if (((Control)sender).Name == "button2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Clicked {control.Name} button");
        }
    }
```